# Haskell Data.Graph graphFromEdges example

Tags: haskell, graph

I'm currently trying to write a GraphML reader for Haskell (see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21035103/2597135)). As I'm quite new to Haskell, despite the steep learning curve I haven't fully managed to learn the ability to deduce examples from the Hackage documentation only.

What I currently have is a `Graph` instance:

```hs
data Graph = Graph
  { graphId :: String,
    nodes :: [String],
    edges :: [(String, String)] -- (Source, target)
  }
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I want to convert them to a [Data.Graph](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Graph.html). I assume `graphFromEdges` or `graphFromEdges'` are the correct functions to do this.

My current attempt is to create the 3-tuples `(nodeid, nodeid, [edge targets])`

```hs
-- Convert a graph node into a Data.Graph-usable
getDataGraphNode :: Graph -> String -> (String, String, [String])
getDataGraphNode graph node = (node, node, getTargets node graph)

-- Convert a Graph instance into a Data.Graph list of (node, nodeid, edge) tuples
getDataGraphNodeList :: Graph -> [(String, String, [String])]
getDataGraphNodeList graph = map (getDataGraphNode graph) (nodes graph)
```

However, GHC won't compile this because of type errors:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `[(node0, key0, [key0])]'
            with actual type `(String, String, [String])'
```

Could you point me to an example, or preferably even describe a general way how to deduce an example from the documentation (function signature, in this case)? Do I need to use the `Vertex` type from Data.Graph? I'm currently unable to figure out what the `node0` and `key0` types need to be.

Here's a minimal example that shows the issue I'm having with `Data.Graph`. I'm unsure of how this relates to misused types, even if many of the errors in my own code occured because of problems with the type system:

```hs
import Data.Graph
main = do
    graph <- graphFromEdges' [("n0","n0",["n1"]), ("n1","n1",["n2"]), ("n2","n2",[])]
    -- This should print ["n0","n1","n2"]
    print $ vertices graph
```

It produces the following error message:

```
bar.hs:4:5:
Couldn't match type `IO' with `(,) Graph'
    Expected type: (Graph, ())
      Actual type: IO ()
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ vertices graph
    In the expression:
      do { graph <- graphFromEdges'
                      [("n0", "n0", ["n1"]), ("n1", "n1", ["n2"]), ....];
           print $ vertices graph }
    In an equation for `main':
        main
          = do { graph <- graphFromEdges' [("n0", "n0", [...]), ....];
                 print $ vertices graph }

bar.hs:4:22:
    Couldn't match type `Vertex -> ([Char], [Char], [[Char]])'
                  with `GHC.Arr.Array Vertex [Vertex]'
    Expected type: Graph
      Actual type: Vertex -> ([Char], [Char], [[Char]])
    In the first argument of `vertices', namely `graph'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `vertices graph'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ vertices graph
```

Comment: What's the `nodeNum` parameter to `getDataGraphNode` supposed to be for? It's not being used and its at least one source of your errors as it means that `getDataGraphNode graph` has type `String -> Int -> (String, String, [String])` so `map (getDataGraphNode graph)` has type `[String] -> [Int -> (String, String, [String])]` (i.e. it produces a list of functions) which is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Ah, sorry, I added that a few minutes before (desperately) posting on SO, because I assumed I have to create a `Vertex` or `Node` from `Data.Graph` -- they seemed to need numeric indices for the nodes. However I think this was entirely the wrong direction.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I removed the nodeNum parameter from the post.

Comment: Can you edit to clarify what code is producing what error message, including the full text of the error message that states what doesn't match what?

Comment: I would expect the fragment you've given (after your edit) to compile, but I may have missed something or your problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I'll try to do that!

Comment: @UliKöhler In the new (edited) form, your code has no obvious type errors. Please include the code that actually produces the error.

Comment: @kosmikus Sorry for the nodeNum confusion. I added a minimal runnable example plus the full error message.

Comment: You've still got the `nodeNum` parameter in the complete example you posted.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam My apologies, I should really have re-checked after copy&pasting

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed I'm passing the Graph directly into `graphFromEdges'`. I'll fix that immediately.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Sorry again for the confusion. I now tried to further condense the issue by removing all custom code (most of the errors in it really seem to be caused by `nodeNum` before). I believe my main problem is the inability to handle the value of the `graphFromEdges'` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import Data.Graph
main = do
    let (graph, vertexMap) = graphFromEdges' [("n0","n0",["n1"]), ("n1","n1",["n2"]),("n2","n2",[])]
    -- This should print ["n0","n1","n2"]
    print $ map ((\ (vid, _, _) -> vid) . vertexMap) (vertices graph)
```

[`graphFromEdges'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Graph.html#v%3agraphFromEdges-39-) returns a pair of values and the `Graph` is the first of that pair. Also, in this context `<-` is for things that return `IO something` whereas `graphFromEdges'` returns a pure value.

The key error was this:

```
Couldn't match type `IO' with `(,) Graph'
    Expected type: (Graph, ())
      Actual type: IO ()
```

although it was reported in a slightly misleading way - the report would have been better if you'd given `main` a type signature `main :: IO ()`. In general if you're confused by type errors it's worth trying to work out what type you think things should be and using explicit type signatures.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the `(graph, _)` syntax is, now that I think about it, quite intuitive (and it help me a lot). However, when `runghc`-ing it, the following error is printed: `graph.hs:3:5:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Char] -> Maybe Vertex'
                with actual type `(Graph, t0)'
`

Comment: `graphFromEdges'` is not in `IO`, so you should `let`-bind it instead. Also, if you really want `["n0","n1","n2"]`, you should do `let (graph, f) = graphFromEdges' ...` and then something like `print $ map ((\ (n, _, _) -> n) . f) (vertices graph)`.

Comment: Apologies, I focused on the tuple and forgot the IO.

Comment: Thanks, the new version mostly works (it prints `[0,1,2]`), I assume you need to keep the second tuple (--> `let (graph, vertexMap) = ...`) to map the vertices.

Comment: Indeed. You probably need to do some playing around with the API and some more experience reading the type error messages to understand what you've got wrong.

Comment: @UliKöhler Just see my comment above.

Comment: @kosmikus Thanks to your code, I figured out how to print `["n0","n1","n2"]`, the edit of Ganeshs post is currently in the review queue! Thanks to both of you for your suggestions!

Comment: people generally reject code changes in suggested edits because they alter the poster's intent, but I've manually applied it now

Comment: Thanks @GaneshSittampalam for your note regarding edits. I don't think it really changed the posts intent, assuming the intent was to provide a correct, runnable example. Because it's explicitly noted (originally from my minimal example, which you copied and edited) that its intent is to print `["n0","n1","n2"]`, so I think it's rather a bugfix, but in no way an intent-changing edit. I don't think posting another answer would be a better solution.

Comment: The edit was fine from my point of view which was why I applied it by hand - it was whoever random hit it in the edit queue that would have rejected it without being aware of the context.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I can see your point now and I fully agree. Thanks again for helping me resolve this issue!